# Google Sheets Filter + Match? Not sure

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula

I have two tabs in a sheet, that have different ranges.  One is preset data, the other is an import from a program we use.  I'm trying to figure out a way, if possible, to pull specific data from sheet 1, and match it with values in sheet two, that aren't sorted the same.

Example sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OsSWQ_48VrcTU3pXGeJ_1syluKPVeVRune39UA9I3x4/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying the formula =sort(filter(Sheet1!B1:B,match(B1:B, Sheet1!B1:B ,0)),2,TRUE), but it's just putting the results in order.  If I replace the column # on the sort with 1, it sorts it out of order but it doesn't match column B, like I need it to.

The documents i'm working with are 2000+ rows each, I'd rather not manually do this if at all possible.

Please assist?  Either way, thank you for reading.

Comment: Can you tell us what the expected result is? sorry I did not understand...

Comment: The expected results are detailed in the example sheet; I need column B on this sheet to look through column B on Sheet 2, and if it finds a match, it appends the number from Sheet1 A to Sheet 2 A on the correct row.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(MATCH( B1:B,Sheet1!$B$1:B,0),{(ROW(Sheet1!A1:A)),Sheet1!A1:A},2,0)))
```

### Explanation

- step#1 `=arrayformula(MATCH( B1:B,Sheet1!$B$1:B,0))` will give the row where each value column B will be found in Sheet1!column B
- step #2 `=arrayformula({ROW(Sheet1!A1:A),Sheet1!A1:A})` will build a virtual matrix whith in column#1 the row and in column#2 the value of Sheet1!column A
- finally: join the two formulas as `vlookup(___step#1____,____step#2______)`

Comment: OMG Thank you!  That works perfectly!  If you ever get bored and feel like explaining the structure of the formula, i'm all ears.  Otherwise, thanks for being amazing!

Comment: I have added a short explanation in my answer and both formulas in the spreadsheet

Comment: Makes perfect sense, and I learned a few new things today.  Thank you!!

Comment: If I understand this, the only reason we can't use a simple VLOOKUP here is that the key values from Sheet1 are not in the leftmost column there. Is that correct?

Comment: High quality solution, thanks!
Slight modification for data on the same sheet:
`=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(MATCH(B1:B,B1:B,0),{(ROW(A1:A)),A1:A},2,0)))`
I had tested that other one before and it did not work for my use case (It returned 53 rows instead of the 83 expected) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yuzBBAwdsM